# How do I retrieve the value of the selecteditems from a listbox?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

This is my first UWP app and I'm sure I just missing something very simple.

I am trying to build an openfilepicker allowing users to select which file types are to be included (.JPEG, .BMP etc) via a listbox.  My problem is the value returned from my listbox is invalid.  The value returned is "my solution name.page name.Classname" not the value that the user has selected in the list box (for example .JPEG").

XAML:

```
        <ListBox x:Name="lstPhotoType" Height="197" SelectionMode="Multiple" FontSize="12" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" SelectionChanged="lstPhotoType_SelectionChanged" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="pictureType" Text="{Binding pType, Mode=TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My c# code:

```
       //Start creating the fileopenpicker.
        FileOpenPicker fileOpenPicker = new FileOpenPicker();
        fileOpenPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;

        //Count the number of selected photos files.
        int count = lstPhotoType.SelectedItems.Count();

        //If 1 of  more photo type/s has been selected - build openpicker filetypefilter.
        if (count > 0)
        {
            foreach (object listBoxItem in lstPhotoType.SelectedItems)
            {
               // string value = Convert.ToString(listBoxItem);
                fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(listBoxItem.ToString());
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Edit 1

My class code for PictureTypes

```
    public class PictureTypes
    {
        public string pType { get; set; }
    }

    string[] arrayoftypes = new string[5] { "*All", ".BMP", ".JPEG", ".JPG", ".PNG"};

    public void makePictureTypeList()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            //Create a new instace of the PictureTypes class
            PictureTypes obj = new PictureTypes();

            //build array of data
            obj.pType = arrayoftypes[i];

            //Add the the picture types into the listbox
            lstPhotoType.Items.Add(obj);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to cast the items in the SelectedItems collection to your type where the "pType" property is defined and access this property directly:

```
if (count > 0)
{
    foreach (PictureTypes listBoxItem in lstPhotoType.SelectedItems.OfType<PictureTypes>())
    {
        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(listBoxItem.pType);
    }
}
```

Or you could use the dynamic type:

```
if (count > 0)
{
    foreach (dynamic listBoxItem in lstPhotoType.SelectedItems)
    {
        fileOpenPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(listBoxItem.pType);
    }
}
```

> Thanks mm8, but debugging still shows pType as "my solution name.page name.Classname

What does "debugging" mean in this case? This will get you the currently selected string values:

```
private void lstPhotoType_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int count = lstPhotoType.SelectedItems.Count();
        if (count > 0)
        {
            foreach (PictureTypes listBoxItem in lstPhotoType.SelectedItems.OfType<PictureTypes>())
            {
                string value = listBoxItem.pType; //<- value = ".BMP" or ".JPG", etc.
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks mm8, but debugging still shows pType as "my solution name.page name.Classname".

Comment: Thanks @mm8, but debugging still shows pType as "my solution name.page name.Classname".

Comment: How is the pType property defined and set? Please post the relevant code snippets.

Comment: public class PictureTypes
        {
            public string pType { get; set; }
        }
string[] arrayoftypes = new string[5] { "*All", ".BMP", ".JPEG", ".JPG", ".PNG"};
public void makePictureTypeList()
{
   for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                //Create a new instace of the PictureTypes class
                PictureTypes obj = new PictureTypes();

                //build array of data
                obj.pType = arrayoftypes[i];

                //Add the the picture types into the listbox
                lstPhotoType.Items.Add(obj);
            }
        }

Comment: The class code has now been added to my question as edit 1.

Comment: See my edit. I am not sure what you are doing but you should cast the items in the SelectedItems collection of the ListBox to a PictureTypes object and then access its pType property.

Comment: Thanks @mm8.  I see what I was doing wrong.  Once I added the code to the selecectionchanged event, I was able toaccess the pType property.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: to get selected item value.

```
string text = listBoxItem.GetItemText(listBoxItem.SelectedItem);
```

**EDIT**

Try below approach
this should work:

```
int index;
string  item;
foreach (int i in lstPhotoType.SelectedIndices)
{
    index = lstPhotoType.SelectedIndex;
    item = lstPhotoType.Items[i].ToString ();
    MessageBox.Show(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ambrish, but my PictureTyes does not contain a definition for GetItemText

Comment: Sorry @Ambrish that should read but my object does not contain a definition for GetItemText.

Comment: Try this: `string text = listBoxItem.SelectedItem.Text;`

Comment: same result -  the object does not contain a definition for SelectedItem.

Comment: Thanks @Ambrish, but ListBox does not contain a definition for selectedindices.